# How to write output to pandas

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas

So the output of a short little iteration of an xml file I did looks like this:

```
{'LegalNm': 'LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC', 'SECRgnCD': 'BRO', 'SECNb': '802-79280', 'FirmCrdNb': '170562', 'BusNm': 'LAUNCH ANGELS'}
{'LegalNm': 'JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, LLC', 'SECRgnCD': 'DRO', 'SECNb': '801-63010', 'FirmCrdNb': '116085', 'BusNm': 'JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT'} .....
```

Basically I want to get everything before the ":" as the header and everything before the comma as going under that header:

```
LegalNm             SECRgnCD   SECNb       FirmCrdNb   ... and so on

LAUNCH ANGELS...    BRO        802-79280   170562
JACOBSEN CAPITAL... DRO        801-63010   116085
```

I was thinking I could use Pandas and store the header names in a list and the "row" names in another but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data frame out of the dictionary and then concatenate them:

```
import pandas as pd
adf = pd.DataFrame(a, index = [0])
bdf = pd.DataFrame(b, index = [1])
pd.concat([adf, bdf], axis = 0)

# BusNm FirmCrdNb   LegalNm SECNb   SECRgnCD
# 0 LAUNCH ANGELS   170562  LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC   802-79280   BRO
# 1 JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT 116085  JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, LLC    801-63010   DRO
```

*Data*:

```
a = {'LegalNm': 'LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC', 'SECRgnCD': 'BRO', 'SECNb': '802-79280', 'FirmCrdNb': '170562', 'BusNm': 'LAUNCH ANGELS'}
b = {'LegalNm': 'JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, LLC', 'SECRgnCD': 'DRO', 'SECNb': '801-63010', 'FirmCrdNb': '116085', 'BusNm': 'JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT'}
```

Comment: One thing I failed to mention is that I have about a thousand or so of these lines each with different values under the headers.  Will this work on that many lines?

Comment: You will have to read them into a list, then loop through or `reduce` the list or combine them into a single dictionary before hand. In that way you can turn the above idea into a loop and it should work.